# Database command 'update' failed: Unknown option to update command: upsert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, rubygems

I am unable to execute upsert query in mongodb version `3.0.12` and ruby gem version is `1.x`. I am using ruby version 1.9.3. I tried upgrading mongodb to version `3.2` and `3.4` but still facing same issue. If anyone has any idea what's going on or faced a similar issue, please give some insights.

```
Database command 'update' failed: Unknown option to update command: upsert
/Users/ayushgaur/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bundler/gems/mongo-ruby-driver-de949571b660/lib/mongo/db.rb:559:in `rescue in command'
/Users/ayushgaur/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bundler/gems/mongo-ruby-driver-de949571b660/lib/mongo/db.rb:555:in `command'
/Users/ayushgaur/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bundler/gems/mongo-ruby-driver-de949571b660/lib/mongo/collection_writer.rb:314:in `block in send_write_command'
/Users/ayushgaur/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bundler/gems/mongo-ruby-driver-de949571b660/lib/mongo/functional/logging.rb:55:in `block in instrument'
/Users/ayushgaur/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bundler/gems/mongo-ruby-driver-de949571b660/lib/mongo/functional/logging.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/ayushgaur/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bundler/gems/mongo-ruby-driver-de949571b660/lib/mongo/functional/logging.rb:54:in `instrument'
/Users/ayushgaur/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bundler/gems/mongo-ruby-driver-de949571b660/lib/mongo/collection_writer.rb:313:in `send_write_command'
/Users/ayushgaur/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bundler/gems/mongo-ruby-driver-de949571b660/lib/mongo/collection.rb:1076:in `send_write'
/Users/ayushgaur/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bundler/gems/mongo-ruby-driver-de949571b660/lib/mongo/collection.rb:497:in `update'
```

Comment: Isn't mongo-ruby-driver up to version 2.4? Why are you on version 1.x?

Comment: Please provide the actual query you've used.

Comment: @eiko There are many dependent gems in the project so I do not want to end up updating all of them.

Comment: @MaximFedotov Query is something like:
    collection.update(
        {
            "param" => param,
        },
        {
            "param1" => param1,
            "param2" => param2
        },
        {
            :upsert => true
        }
    )

Comment: @eiko And also it's not like 1.x does not support upsert command.

Answer (score 0):

mongo-ruby-driver 1.x does not fully support mongodb 3, as per https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/announcing-ruby-driver-20-rewrite:

> There are many reasons to upgrade to mongo gem version 2.0 and to mongoid gem version 5.0, when it’s released. First off, these versions support MongoDB 3.0 [...]
>   New features will not be added and development work will consist only of bug fixes and minimal features necessary for supporting the most recent version of the server.

I searched the entire Internet for people with a similar problem, and the only people I found were those at pagerbot, who were using the 1.x series of gem with mongo 3 and getting the exact same error as you:

https://github.com/stripe-contrib/pagerbot/issues/46

They resolved the error by updating to mongo-ruby-driver 2. Apologies for making you wrestle with those dependencies, but I could not find an easier answer.